# How can I make them the same?

Tags: javascript

Why isn't the title info1 and li the same?
How can I make them the same?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `li` is a DOM, not a string, using innerHTML for get string from tag html

try `console.log(titleinfo[1]==li.innerHTML)` on `line 446`

Comment: yup, if this helped you, plz accept my answer. I very happy :))